# How I can access to the next page in django 2.0

Tags: django, models

I have the following scenery. In the first page there are type of products, when choose specific type it sends to the page of products of the specific type, then when I choose the product it should send me to the page of the product where there is full information about the product. But I can't access the last product page. How I should fix this? My code:

views.py:

```
def products_fizlitso(request):

 fizlitso_product = InsuranceProducts.objects.filter(product_type="Физическое 
 Лицо")

 context = {'fizlitso_product': fizlitso_product}
 return render(request, 'insurance_products/fizlitso/fizlitso.html', context)


def fizlitso_type(request, type_id):

 product_type = get_object_or_404(InsuranceProducts, id=type_id)

 context = {'product_type': product_type}
 return render(request, 'insurance_products/fizlitso/fizlitso_type.html', 
 context)

def product_page(request, product_id):

 product = get_object_or_404(ProductType, id=product_id)

 context = {'product': product}
 return render(request, 'insurance_products/fizlitso/product.html', context)
```

here is the urls.py:

```
# ******************************************************************
path('fizlitso/', views.products_fizlitso, name='product_fizlitso'),
# ******************************************************************

# ******************************************************************
path('fizlitso/product_type<int:type_id>', views.fizlitso_type, name='fizlitso_type'),
# ******************************************************************

# ******************************************************************
path('fizlitso/product_type<int:type_id>/product<int:product_id>', views.product_page, name='product_page'),
# ******************************************************************
```

and here is the django part of the template which holds all the product types:

```
  {% for product in fizlitso_product %}
  <div class="btmspace-80">
    <h3>{{ product.product_area }}</h3>
    <img class="imgr borderedbox inspace-5" src="{% static 'img/imgr.gif' %}" alt="">
    <p>
        {{ product.product_description }}
    </p>

    <p>
        Подробно вы можете узнать <a href="{% url 'main:fizlitso_type' product.id %}">здесь</a></a>
    </p>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

And here the django part of the template which holds all the products of the specific type:

```
  {% for product in product_type.producttype_set.all %}
  <div class="btmspace-80">
    <h3>{{ product.title }}</h3>
    <img class="imgr borderedbox inspace-5" src="{% static 'img/imgr.gif' %}" alt="">
    <p>
        {{ product.description }}
    </p>

    line 84  <p>
      Подробно вы можете узнать <a href="{% url 'main:product_page' product.id %}">здесь</a></a>
    </p>
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
```

And here is the page about the specific product chosen from above page:

```
    <div class="btmspace-80">
    <h3>{{ product.title }}</h3>
    <img class="imgr borderedbox inspace-5" src="{% static 'img/imgr.gif' %}" alt="">
    <p>
        {{ product.description }}
    </p>
  </div>
```

And this one is the error:

> NoReverseMatch at /fizlitso/product_type1
>
> Reverse for 'product_page' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1
>   pattern(s) tried:
>   ['fizlitso\/product_type(?P[0-9]+)\/product(?P[0-9]+)$']
>
> C:\Users\Lenovo
>   101\PycharmProjects\uzagro_3\main\templates\insurance_products\fizlitso\fizlitso_type.html,
>   error at line 84

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your url name product_page have two parameters:type_id,product_id

```
path('fizlitso/product_type<int:type_id>/product<int:product_id>', views.product_page, name='product_page')
```

you give one?

```
<a href="{% url 'main:product_page' product.id %}">
```

Comment: You mean I should pass, two arguments product_id and type_id?

Comment: `<a href="{% url 'polls:product_page'  type_id  product.id  %}">здесь</a> ` try it

Comment: Yep, it did work, also you need to pass type_id to the view function, thank you bro for ur help1